Some Questions On The Historicity Of Hindu Puranas
Was there an actual historical Purana during the Vedic period? which was the collection of mythologies and legends of the pre-Mahabharata ages??
how much of the 18 Maha Puranas were actually compiled by Vyasa at the end of Dwapar Yug (5000 years ago)??
how much changes were brought on to these puranas...and are there puranas which were entirely conceived during and after the Gupta golden age of ancient India?
[for example, I heard some say Kalki and Bhavisya Puranas were written and compiled during the Islamic age and the Hindu holocausts.]
is there any study on the interpolations that are found in the Puranas?? can anyone provide links if you know?

Puranas all 18 of the them are authored by Bhagavan veda vyasa a.k.a Naryana in rishi form. Ramayana was quoted  in many prehistoric stories like naldyamayanthi. for mahabharata to be quoted the mahabharata should have happened we see reference name krishna before Krishna was even born. most of the purunas are interpoloated to   complie with existing phiolosphy primary advaita.. except bhagavata, but this also was interpoloated later 2000bc which sriman madvacharaya corrected to current prlevant version

It is said as per tradition that there was one single Purana initially. Also, the mention of Purana as a term is found as early as Brahmanas and Upanishads so something similar definitely existed back then. Further, stories similar to Puranas are found even in Brahmana literature.
There is no reason to believe that the earliest version of most major Puranas did not exist at the time of Vyasa when he bifurcated them with the Vedas.
Now, comes the tricky part. Puranas were not mantras with potency or used in rituals.  Hence their transmission was not done the Vedic way but through schools of Brahmanas and Sutas by oral transmission. By the time of the early centuries AD, when they were committed to writing, there was interpolation although not a lot. They are not free from interpolation.
Now, one can use logic to deduce interpolations. Portions that completely contradict Shrutis, ideas that occur out of the blue with zero cross reference in any Vedic text or Itihasa and ofcourse references to Mughals, Guptas or any royal lineage are interpolations. This does not mean the entire text is a late composition.
As for Bhavishya Purana, since almost the entire Purana only talks about historical events and heavily of medieval Era, it is generally said to be not one composed by Vyasa.


Shrimad Bhagvat Purana from Geeta Press is based on thirteenth century manuscript. Reference is found in preface of vol 1 itself.
Original manuscript is kept in Sampoornanand Sanskrit Vishwavidyalaya, Varanasi. https://www.ssvv.ac.in/



Hindus didn't lie or cheat before British education ruined the society (1836). This is mostly recorded and observed by scholars like Padma Bhushana Prof. Kapil Kapoor.



Even if someone tried to, others bought him to justice with help of Kings (till about 1800 AD). Reference Adhyatmic Gita by Bhupendranath Sanyal.

